# How can I display the Ok () message from the IHttpActionResult in c #?

Tags: c#, api

I am new to the area of api rest in c #, currently develop an Api rest, which is the following:

I am using the Ok () method to return response 200 of the query, but how can I integrate that answer into my Json?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int _IdCanal, int _TipoAvance)
    {
        var lista_coutas = await _conexion.GetCuotas(_IdCanal, _TipoAvance);

        if (lista_coutas == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(lista_coutas);
    }
```

which returns the following Json:

```
   {
    "Cuotas": [
            {
                "opcion": 1,
                "cuota": 12
            },
            {
                "opcion": 2,
                "cuota": 10
            },
            {
                "opcion": 3,
                "cuota": 8
            },
            {
                "opcion": 4,
                "cuota": 6
            },
            {
                "opcion": 5,
                "cuota": 5
            },
            {
                "opcion": 6,
                "cuota": 3
            }
    }
```

I am using the Ok () method to return response 200 of the query, but how can I integrate that answer into my Json?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the response code to the json object returned? If so, why not use the response code returned by the request itself?

Comment: @JonathonChase So enter the method Ok () in the code where I generate the Json, right?

Answer (score 0):

AS stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results), you can return a HttpResponseMessage.